# How to check if the values in an array correspond to values in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, correspondence

I have a cell array called `grnPixels` of size `(1 x 40)`, where each individual cell has an `M x 1` vector array of numbers where `M` is variable. I also have a single vector array called `redCentroid` of size `N x 1`.

I want to check if the values in `redCentroid` correspond to any values in `grnPixels`. I have made a code but it is **extremely slow** in this Matlab code. How can I improve this?

```
nRedCells = length(propsRed);
nGrnCells = length(propsGrn);
grnPixels = cell(1,nGrnCells);
redCentroid = zeros(nRedCells,1);
matchMemory = zeros(nRedCells,1);

for j = 1:nRedCells
    for i = 1:nGrnCells
        for n = 1:length(grnPixels{i})
            matchment = ismember(redCentroid(j),grnPixels{i}(n));
            if matchment == 1
                matchMemory(j,1:2) = [j i];
            end
            continue
        end
     end
 end
```

Sample Data

```
redCentroid

51756
65031
100996
118055
122055
169853
197175
233860
244415
253822

grnPixels{1}

142
143
100996
167
168

grnPixels{2}

537
538
539
540
541
542
233860
244415
545
546
547
548
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ismember` can accept a matrix for both the first or second input so there is no need for the outer loop or the most inner loop.

```
matchMemory = zeros(numel(redCentroid), 2);

for k = 1:numel(grnPixels)
    % Check which of the centroids are in grnpixels
    isPresent = ismember(redCentroid, grnPixels{k});

    % If they were present fill in the first column with the index in red
    matchMemory(isPresent, 1) = find(isPresent);

    % Fill in the second column with the index in green
    matchMemory(isPresent, 2) = k;
end
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to tell me that `Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent` in `cat(2, grnPixels{:})`.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Just made a small tweak.

Comment: So are all of the elements of the green pixel array not `M x 1` like you've said?

Comment: Also, I don't seem to be getting the indices of the values when I use the previous for-loop code you provided. The line `matchMemory(j,1:2) = [j i]` is key.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Please provide some simple example data that I can run then.

Comment: The cell array is `49 x 1` and can change. The arrays inside the cell array are of different size `209 x 1` or `100 x 1`, etc.

Comment: Ok well typically "each individual cell has an M x 1 vector array of numbers" would indicate that each element has the same size. I'll update it and if you can provide some example data I can actually test it

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I have added some sample data.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find any matches regardless of order

1. Copy the two matrices to two other matrices if you want the original matrices to remain unchanged.
2. Sort both of the new matrices individually
3. Compare the lowest elements of the two matrices
4. If they match, store the element in some collector array
5. If they don't, move to the next number in the set with the lowest number.
6. Repeat steps 2 through 4 until you have gone through one set.
7. The collector array will contain all the matches.

This should run in 2*M*log(M)+2*M time.

If you want to find the indices in the original matrices that correspond to the matches, just compare each element in the collector array with the elements of both matrices, record the index whenever a match is found, and continue until you reach the end.

If the elements are in a specific order, like coordinates, just compare element 1 in the first set to element 1 in the second set.